# The Woman and Bird in the Night: Can you solve the riddle related to this painting?

Tags: number-sequence, visual

At my school we have this thing called the breakout box and there's a challenge. It's pretty hard, so me and some of my friends have been working on it. The idea is that there is a box with a bunch of locks on it and clues around the room to help unlock it. You have to use the clues to get the locks' codes - a 4 digit number - and open the box. So far we've opened every single lock except one. We've researched for about two days and we can't figure this out, so I decided that I would ask the online community.

The riddle is on the wall. There is this painting and we found out the painting is called 'The Woman and Bird in the Night'. It's by Joan Miro. (see below) The teacher who made the riddles wrote 'e=16' in the bottom corner on the white part of the paper. We aren't sure if this is a hint, a key, or something to throw you off. We really need help with this because we have unlocked all the locks except one. This is the only clue left, and the answer must be a 4-digit combination.

I'll be checking for answers about every hour.

Here is the picture:

[image: The Woman and Bird in the Night]

[Here](http://www.wikiart.org/en/joan-miro/not_detected_227979#supersized-artistPaintings-227979) is a link to a larger version of the painting if anyone needs it.

It might seem like this has many answers, but there is only one answer and it is a four digit combo that uses numbers. I do have access to the lock and every day I have been going down and checking all the combos that people have thought might be a possible answer and then adding a comment letting people know if anyone was right.

Here is a pic of the picture on the wall:[image]
[image]

Comment: @Conner, welcome to Puzzling SE. The community is much more likely to help you and will be able to help you much more easily is you were to take a little time working on the formatting and punctuation of your question.

Comment: There was a lot of rambling. If anyway wants to restore any of the backstory (this is apparently a puzzle in a set of puzzles that are to be used to unlock a series of locks), go right ahead.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing it looks good if anyone is wondering why my spelling is bad it's because i have dislexia

Comment: also still no answer if anyone thinks the figured out something that may help please leave it as a comment.

Comment: @conner Sometimes puzzles take days or even months to be solved.  You haven't given a whole lot to work with, so it may be that it is never solved.  Of course, you never know.  Someone could figure it out.

Comment: @conner Is there anything else that could potentially be relevant to solving the puzzle?  Could it be based on the solutions of the previous puzzles?

Comment: I have checked that out and no i didnt find anything but the guy who painted it is very famous and i guess he paints with a style and when u look at it you can see diffrent thing depending on the person that might have something to do with it

Comment: Do you have any way of checking the 4-digit number? Could it be (maybe, related to) 1971 or 1975, which are the years the painting was started or finished?

Comment: ya i can i have tried those but i well try agin tomorrow to make sure

Comment: if all else fails, I would just try all the combinations. At one combination per second that would only take 2.5 hours.

Comment: @Slepz Yeah, one could probably achieve one-second tests using de Bruijn sequences. Also, the correct one should be somewhere in the middle :-)

Comment: @Carl Löndahl I'd probably try all the 1900's first

Comment: sounds like a good idea if no results turn up soon ill try that but would be nice if i could get some more possible combinations

Comment: I'm assuming the digits available in the 4-digit code are just 0-9? In other words, this isn't a combo lock where each number goes up to 50 or something, is it?

Comment: I wonder who is that person that decided to give this -1? What type of research he seeks...

Comment: ya its a 4 digit 0-9 code

Comment: Is it related to Fibonacci numbers (those black twin circles connected by string) ?

Comment: The orange thing on bottom right looks like a G key, and the connected dots might be quavers, so could it be related to music somehow?

Comment: Is it 8433 or 8223 (or permutations of it)?

Comment: @conner, what are the previous lock's combinations? could you give us a list? how many locks were there in total?

Comment: Observation: There are 8 pairs of black circles connected together in the painting. In other words, 16 black circles. "e=16" might be hinting that this is relevant somehow? By the way, could something that teacher taught your class be relevant here? Also it might be helpful if you briefed us on some of the other puzzles you solved to open the other locks. I know you already said that you thought they weren't relevant but you can't be sure until after you've solved this one. :P

Comment: Im also curious on how you can be certain all the digits have to be found on this painting.

Comment: btw i see the letter  S, T, and 68.  if e = 16  s=30 t31. my first try would be 3068, second 3031

Comment: The artist actually has **4** pieces with this same title. [This one](http://www.wikiart.org/en/joan-miro/not_detected_227934) seems to be a permutation of that one.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys i am going to try all them new combos u guys have come up with today at luch i well tell you if any work as for answering some of your questions we also thought that the numbers might be on some of the other clues we have checked that out and un fourtentley came up with nothing their are clues on the walls and stuff and every clue has been used some of the clues were moris code eygiption symbols but all the other clues all came up with a code and their isnt any clues that havent given us a answer but this lock and theirs only one lock left.

Comment: so i just tryed all of the combos u guys have put and non of them worked so keep up the good work and keep trying please thanks!!!

Comment: Hello! I've put this question on hold as too broad, since it seems (at least from these comments) like there are too many ways to come to solutions with no obvious way of telling if they're correct. If you encounter more information which could limit the number of possible solutions, please do edit it in, though!

Comment: Can you show us a picture of where he wrote "e=16"? It may not actually be "e=16", it may be intended to be looked at another way which could be another clue.

Comment: Try the following four numbers: 1024, 2048, 4096 and 8192 (following from E = 16, A could be 1, B = 2, C = 4, D = 8, and so on). If there is one letter which stands out between J to M, then that might be the solution. Interestingly, J and M are the first letters of the artist's name

Comment: so the e=16 is just in the bottem right corner it's not on the picture the picture is printed on paper and it dosent take the entire paper and the e=16 is on the part of the paper that dosent have the picture printed on also to the guy who put my question on hold because he said it was to broad  i would like to ask that you un hold it because their isnt more than one answer it's a four digit combo and i can test them to find out if their right and every day i have been testing new answers if the lock dosent open it isnt right.

Comment: PLEASE use punctuation. It's impossible to tell what you're saying.

Comment: With the parameters we currently have, it is too broad. Could you post the other clues and answers, to help narrow down? Or, as other users have asked, give a photo of the actual clue, with the teacher's modifications? As you have described it, there are too many unknowns to get to the desired answer.

Comment: I would use the earlier puzzles to help give values to other letters. Perhaps d is 15, c is 14, etch. Then add up the letter in the title of the painting. If it comes to more than 4 digits try the name of the artist. Still no luck? Try other ways of mapping letters to numbers. Since it's a 4 digit code I would also try just the artists last name - no adding just the single digits for miro. That sort of thing.

Comment: So on monday i am going to add a picture of the pic on the wall so that their well be a new clue I will also post a pic of the few other clues could u please put it off hold before monday so that people can still work on it and see it tell then on monday it well become a race and i would also like to put a bounty on it on monday so i need to to be open so i can get more things for the bounty and so it well be old enough to place a bounty on monday

Comment: $2326_8=JM_{36}$

Comment: Maybe e = 16 is the key for a Caesar cipher?

Comment: I have tryed and so far non of theise answers were correct but keep up the good work sorry for not responding for a while ive been busy in school

Comment: Can you try the following two combinations: 1895, 1819? Thank you

Comment: What is the answer!

Comment: Have you tried 1975?

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the picture: if the only information were "e=16" then the most logical solution would be that a=1, b=2, c=4, and d=8 yielding 1248. Give it a shot if you haven't already.

Comment: I think I solved it. My answer is found below

Answer (score 6):

The solution requires understanding of Joan Miro's artwork. There are 7 paintings of his that are titled "Women and Bird in the Night". Each of them are different, but there are two that stand out that share a common element. The element (e) is represented as such:

[image]

In this case, the image represents 2 (because of two nodes). In the image you shared, there were 16 nodes in the drawing. The e = 16 could potentially point out that there are 16 nodes in the graph.

I compiled all the paintings with the same name here, and marked the nodes:

[image: The paintings of similar names]

So, the two possible combinations are 1614 or 1416

Answer (score 2):

Looks like 5468 or 5408 to me...

[image]

Comment: Nice. But this does not explain "e=16".

Comment: True, 5 + 4 + 0 + 8 = 17. Might still be worth a try, since some (diabolical) people I know would do that to mess someone up :D